# Get src from image inside button that you have clicked.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the SRC from an image inside a button that i have to press to open a accordion (bootstrap). What I want, is to get the src from the image that is inside the button but I cannot seem to find a good example of what I am looking for. Only the src value from when you click the image itself.

My current code:

```js
function collapse() {
    console.log("Help!");
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style>
    #collapseimg {
      width: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" onclick="collapse()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
   <img id="collapseimg" src="collapse-close.png" />
           Is het nodig een afspraak te maken?
         </button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So what do I want? I want to get the current src value from the img with the ID: collapseimg. But only the one inside the button that I have clicked.

Kind regards,
Robbert

Comment: @I.Manev that only works if there is one img with the that ID, i only need the one inside the actuall button that i have clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First don't use inline JavaScript. Instead bind to the element you need. Then use `this`, `.find()`, and `.attr()` to get the image's `src` property, `$(this).find('img').attr('src')`:

```js
$('button.btn.btn-link').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).find('img').attr('src'))
})
```

```css
#collapseimg {
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
   <img id="collapseimg" src="collapse-close.png" />
           Is het nodig een afspraak te maken?
         </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<script src="main.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

As IDs have to be unique in the document, you could simply use:

```
var button = document.getElementById("collapseimg");
var hrefVal = button.getAttribute("src");
```

If you have multiple buttons and you want to fetch the image within the clicked button (without using any IDs) you can do that via the click event.

```
var handleClick = function(event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target;
    // using jQuery here, since mentioned in your tags:
    var imageSrc = $(buttonClicked).find("img").eq(0).attr("src");
}
```

And i have to concur with j08691. Don't use inline JS.