# Change img and styling to elements above collapse body

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have been struggling with this for a few hours now. I finally got it to work so that the img and text change when i click on the button. But after trying a few things I noticed that it does not work as I want it to.

When I click on a collapse button, it changes perfectly, also how I want it too. But when I open another collapse the text stays gold and does not change back.

I want it to be so that when a collapse is opened the above text is gold but when its closed the above text turns back to the original color.

How can I achieve such result?

```js
$('button.btn.btn-link').click(function() {
  var imgsrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
  if (imgsrc == "http://i.imgur.com/xkGbQeg.png") {
    $(this).addClass("goldtext");
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/Q3ickhr.png");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("goldtext");
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/xkGbQeg.png");
  }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style>
    #collapseimg {
      width: 15px;
    }
    
    .goldtext {
      color: #d6c095 !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
   <img id="collapseimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/xkGbQeg.png" />
           Is het nodig een afspraak te maken?
         </button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <img id="collapseimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/xkGbQeg.png" />
            Is het nodig een afspraak te maken?
            </button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Kind regards,
Robbert

Comment: "Robbert"... Are you using multiple user identities on SO? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48787894/get-src-from-image-inside-button-that-you-have-clicked/48787997

Comment: @ZimSystem Yea, I wanted to ask this question on that account wich is my work account but I had to wait 90 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i notice is that your function run when an especific button is clicked, but it does check if there is another one open.

I added a var to save the opened element. The logic with this is the next cases:

1. Element 1 and Element 2 are close. Yo click one element and it openes and changes the font color. This is your if(true) value. Here open will save the element 1
2. Element 1 is open. You click on element 1 so it closes and changes the font color to blue. This is your else part of the function. We reset the open var
3. Last and the important case. Element 1 is open. You click on element two. This will close element 1 and go into your if(true) part of the functio. Open will have the element 1 value. So when it goes in the if part it will encounter the next if.

   if (open != null) {
         open.removeClass("goldtext");
       }

   > Code doesnt want to farmat correctly
   >   And reset its font color.

I hope my code help you. If you need more help, i'll be happy in helping you.

```js
//Var to save opened element
open = null;


$('button.btn.btn-link').click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parents()[2]
  var child = parent.children[1];
  var changer = child.classList.contains('show');
  var imgsrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

  if (!changer) {
    if (open != null) {
      open.removeClass("goldtext");
      open.find('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/xkGbQeg.png");
    }
    $(this).addClass("goldtext");
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/Q3ickhr.png");
    //Save clicked and opened element
    open = $(this);
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("goldtext");
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/xkGbQeg.png");
    open = null;
  }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style>
    #collapseimg {
      width: 15px;
    }
    
    .goldtext {
      color: #d6c095 !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
   <img id="collapseimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/xkGbQeg.png" />
           Is het nodig een afspraak te maken?
         </button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <img id="collapseimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/xkGbQeg.png" />
            Is het nodig een afspraak te maken?
            </button>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: Change some selector to obtain the class list of the panel. This class changes form collapse to show. Cahnge the if to validate the class show value.

Comment: It does not work exactly like I want it to. When you open the top, than the bottom and then the top again, it does not change to gold again. Also if you double click by accident the classes get switched (gold when closed - gray when opened). Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: But this isnt you changing the font color, it also is changing your image. Can you maybe put some online images so we can test it correctly

Comment: Ok so we have that problem

Comment: I will delete this question and go from the new snippet

Comment: @Granny still working on it. Have to go to class. Hope to help in a few

Comment: No worries bud :)

Comment: @Granny i was able to do some changes and i think we are close. What do you think?

Comment: @Granny Happy it did. Please do not forget to upvote and accepting the answer. Although we love to help,we also love those reputation point. Code on!